# Does TypeORM auto generated migration files needs to add IF NOT EXISTS somewhere?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, migration, documentation, typeorm

As far as [the docs](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/migrations#running-and-reverting-migrations) mention TypeORM is smart enough to **not** run twice a success migration file.

Therefore I can't find about the need or not to add IF NOT EXISTS when creating a new table, column, etc...

Would add IF NOT EXISTS needed for auto generated migration scripts?

Answer (score 1):

Usually TypeORM keeps track of the migrations that were ran using a table (I think it is also called migrations).

This means that TypeORM won't run a migration twice, regardless if it was auto generated or not. So, you don't have to add a IF NOT EXISTS statement for creating tables or columns.

Comment: Do you have any documentation about this? Pls

Answer (score 1):

While it's true that TypeORM keeps track of migrations, our team faced several conflicting migration related production issues, and solving it is a dirty task. Especially in prod. The bigger the team, the more likely you'll encounter issues.

I **highly recommend** everyone to make sure the migrations are modified so they check for existence. It takes very little manual labour, but other than that it has literally 0 downsides. However, it could save you some headache on the long run.